# How can I make my commit history work with git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a history that looks like this

```
H o updated ctools, ds
G M─┐ merged module file
F │ o find page 
E o │ work on download restriction
D o─┘ Report downloading/emailing WIP
C o migration: find and replace URLs throughout notes
B o various local things
A o initial commit
```

Further behind, A comes off of a remote master. Now the remote has moved on and I'd like to use git rebase to update my history to be on top of the latest remote changes.

All of these commits are on code that is **not in** the remote master, but git rebase will fail me because it seems to not understand how to process **D:G**: the side branch that was merged at **G**. Git rebase attempts to apply them in order, without the merge, i.e. `A B C D E F H...` but **F** will not apply on **E**. I plan on needing to rebase several times to keep my code on top of the latest origin's development, so I want a lasting solution.

How can I tell git that the answer to the conflict is to be found at **G**? Or how can I do something else such that git rebase will be able to reply commits? I'd happily squash **D:G** into **D'** if that made things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git merge with master is the best option in your scenario, as rebase isn't designed for merge commits (G is your problem here). But if you really want to and `git rebase -p` didn't produce the desired result, you can:

1. rebase A-E (which is then A'-E')
2. reapply F separately (by cherrypick or otherwise) on top of D' to become F'
3. merge E' and F' to become G'
4. cherrypick H on top of G'

Other reasons why merge is preferred here:

1. Those commits you are trying to rebase probably already belong to some feature branch on the remote, rebasing a lot of them onto another remote branch will simply result in a whole lot of duplicate commits, which can be confusing to others.
2. If those commits are only in your local branch, by rebasing (but not necessarily pushing) them you are effectively "withholding" them until the time they finally get pushed or merged. This can be disruptive to others as it will look like a huge number of commits suddenly appeared out of nowhere within a short period of time; merging should be a regular activity in the workflow.

That said, if you plan to do regular rebase for any reason whatsoever (such as working with git-svn), the best way is to maintain a linear history for the commits that you wish to rebase and/or limit them to a small number. For a series of commits involving merges, those merges need to be collapsed from front to back (like mini rebases).

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I say, I'm going to need to repeat this regularly, so I really like the sound of your 1-5 as a one time fix. Could you give more pointers on how to do this partial rebasing in (1)? Also, if I can do this, then wouldn't it be easier to rebase A-D, then get a patch D:G, apply that as E', then use rebase again on the rest (H goes on and on, and there are other examples of this branched-then-merged in the rest of the tree).

Comment: @artfulrobot you can squash some of the commits, but this has to be done at your own discretion as the intent of the original commits is not always preserved. If H goes on and on, merge is strongly encouraged.

Comment: Bit of context: the origin is Drupal. Most of my code is in a new module; specific to my use; that will never be part of the origin. A few occasions I patch the core drupal. When Drupal brings out a security update, I want my code to apply on top of that. Any of my core patches I will want to review as they may no longer be necessary/right. I share these patches with my various drupal projects, which is why rebase is nice. Merging would make this process more messy and I'd lose my patches.

Comment: @artfulrobot in that case I will recommend that keep your core patches in a separate branch and maintain them in a fashion that makes rebase easier.